# How to concatenate 3 query results with a slash and display in another column with SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Tables - 'BAT' and 'SET'.

SET Table has the following columns:

- ID (Primary Key)
- QC_RUN_ID

BAT Table has the following columns:

- BATSET_ID (This is the foreign key to map the BAT to the SET)
- CREATED_DATE
- DTE_ID
- BAT_NAME
- ETA

The below 3 statements work fine:

Statement 1:

```
select to_char(CREATED_DATE,'DDMONYYY') AS PART1 from BAT WHERE DTE_ID = '33782451' AND BAT_NAME LIKE '110_170_ECM 140_%';
```

Result (PART1):

```
25JUL016
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT SET.QC_RUN_ID AS PART2
FROM SET
INNER JOIN BAT
ON SET.ID=BAT.BATSET_ID
WHERE BAT.DTE_ID = '33782451' AND BAT.BAT_NAME LIKE '110_170_ECM 140_%'
```

Result (PART2):

```
7947492
```

Statement 3:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.ETA, INSTR(t.ETA, '=')+1, (INSTR(t.ETA, 'type')-INSTR(t.ETA, '='))-2) AS PART3
  FROM BAT t
  WHERE t.DTE_ID = '33782451' AND t.BAT_NAME LIKE '110_170_ECM 140_%'
```

Result (PART3):

```
153464685
```

**My Requirement:**

I have to concatenate PART1, PART2 and PART3 results with a slash in between using a single query and display it as another column with a SELECT statement.

The resultant output should be like this:

```
 25JUL016\7947492\153464685
```

How can I do this? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following the queries correctly, then you just need to modify the second one to get what you want:

```
SELECT (to_char(t.CREATED_DATE,'DDMONYYY') || '/' ||
        SET.QC_RUN_ID || '/' ||
        SUBSTR(t.ETA, INSTR(t.ETA, '=')+1, (INSTR(t.ETA, 'type')-INSTR(t.ETA, '='))-2)
       )
FROM SET INNER JOIN
     BAT t
     ON SET.ID = t.BATSET_ID
WHERE t.DTE_ID = '33782451' AND t.BAT_NAME LIKE '110_170_ECM 140_%';
```

If the three queries were not combinable, you could do something like this:

```
select (q1.col || '/' || q2.col || '/' q3.col)
from (<query1>) q1 cross join
     (<query2>) q2 cross join
     (<query3>) q3;
```

But I don't think the subqueries are necessary.